# How do I add a 0 to null values from sql server?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm pulling numbers from sql server using streamwriter to populate a text file. But it's cutting off the first number if it's 0. How do I automatically add that number in the text file if the string is only 8 characters long?

```
  Dim outputStream As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fileName)

        'Get all values from the current item on the reader as long as Read() returns true...
        Do While reader.Read
            'make an array the length of the available fields
            Dim values(reader.FieldCount - 1) As Object
            'get all the field values
            reader.GetValues(values)

            'write the text version of each value to a comma seperated string
            Dim line As String = String.Format("{0,-10}" & vbTab & "{1,-20}" & vbTab & "{2,-1}", values)
            'write the csv line to the file
            outputStream.WriteLine("091869" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & line)
        Loop
```

So right now if the number is (011111111) it comes back (11111111) instead of (011111111). I need the whole number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select right('000000000'+convert(varchar(9), NUMBER), 9)
```

this will right-justify, zero-fill the number to 9 characters.  Adjust as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the sql query.  I don't know what the statement is now, but you can convert the column to a varchar(9) in the SQL query to keep it from cutting off the trailing 0.